# generate pdf report on button click

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

i  just want to see all the report on a pdf format on button click.
i use ...

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Create Document class object and set its size to letter and give space left, right, Top, Bottom Margin
    Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);
    //Write some content
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("This is my first line using Paragraph.");
    Phrase pharse = new Phrase("This is my second line using Pharse.");
    Chunk chunk = new Chunk(" This is my third line using Chunk.");
    // Now add the above created text using different class object to our pdf document

    doc.Add(paragraph);

    doc.Add(pharse);

    doc.Add(chunk);
    doc.Close(); //Close document

}
```

but not effective

Comment: I guess you have to add the report to the response stream ...

Answer (score 2):

Your button click is simply creating a document in memory, writing to it and closing it.

You need to output the document to the `Response.Output` stream.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
protected void PrintButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsValid) return;
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    using (var document = new Document())
    {
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
        document.Open();
        document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello PDF!"));
        document.Close();
    }
}
```

The main thing that you were missing was the PdfWriter which writes the document to the Response.OutputStream